# Projection (VGA) issues using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Dell Inspiron 5547 (HDMI)

Tags: projector

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series(5547) laptop with Windows 8.1 (64-bit).  It has HDMI with 15.6 inches display, with AMD Radeon Graphics and with intel CORE i5 processor. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS- dual boot.  I use a projector using a HDMI to VGA adaptor.  Booting into windows and using the projector is not an issue.

Problem: When I boot into Ubuntu, only the task bar with all the icons in it and the background color of desktop is showing on the projection. Any repositioning of icons within the taskbar is reflected  but the mouse pointer, all files/folders on the Ubuntu desktop or any pop-up windows/menus are not being reflected on the projection.

Please suggest a solution.  I am a novice as far as familiarity with Ubuntu or Linux is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using the extended mode, you can drag a window to the right (over your desktop monitor), and it shall be displayed in the projector.

Or, you can change your display setting in the "System Settings"
[image: Extended mode]

Tick the "Mirror displays" to use the mirrored mode.
[image: mirrored mode]

Comment: Moving the windows past the right side of the laptop computer screen made them visible on the projection screen but I was unable to see them on my laptop screen.  Checking the mirror displays option using the "System Setting" worked fine.  Thanks.